# ReactJS Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable

I have a `LessonEditor` component that passes down to children components props with a function called `setValues`:

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    title: 'This is a long lesson title lol lol',
    desc: 'This is a description',
    location: '1',
    content: 'I\'m a poteto',
});

const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    console.log(name + value);
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
};
```

The first component to which I pass props is:

```
<LessonContents

    editing={editing}
    title={values.title}
    desc={values.desc}
    content={values.content}
    location={values.location}

    setValues={handleChange} // right here
/>
```

Then inside `LessonContents` I have another component where I pass the `setValues` function:

```
<TextEditor
    content={props.content}
    setContent={props.setValues}
/>
```

Then finally inside the TextEditor the code is:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function TextEditor(props) {

    return (
        <div
            suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
            id='editor'
            contentEditable
            onKeyDown={(e) => props.setContent('content', e.target.innerHTML)}
        >
            {props.content}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The error is triggered when I try to type text in the `contentEditable` div. Why?

EDIT: now I just realized that also the input text fields are causing the error, **but if I delete this code contained in LessonContent.js the input text are working again:**

```
            <div className='box-content justify-left'>
                <LessonLocation
                    location={props.location}
                    setLocation={props.setValues}
                 />
            </div>
            <div className='box-content justify-left'>
                <TextEditor
                    content={props.content}
                    setContent={props.setValues}
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: Not able to re-create the issue, can you provide the codepen?

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/sickdyd/ez-class/tree/master/front_end

Comment: It is not the error you highlighted.

Comment: I don't know why the error is different when executed in codesandbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why this is happening, but if I disable updating on your LessonLocation component, the error stops:

```js
export default class LessonLocation extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const data = {
      label: 'hello',
      value: 'hello'
    }

    return <Tree data={data}></Tree>
  }
};
```

It has to do with the `<Tree />` updating. I don't know why it even updates, it doesn't seem like it needs the data you use. You should try to implement a check into shouldComponentUpdate() yourself if you need it to update based on the data.